Movie where husband is killed and wife ends up surrogate mother to weird murderous jungle children?
I am trying to remember a movie I saw a few years ago. Unfortunately, I only remember bits and pieces, so here's everything I remember (and I hope, but make no promises that, I'm remembering it right), in no particular order:

The movie was in color and on dvd, not too terribly old, I think.
It takes place in possibly a Chinese or South American jungle on/near a river.
One thing that sticks out in my mind is the weird ramshackle wooden buildings that I think were burnt out or just not built well?
The husband gets murdered, I think, or possibly barely escapes at the end.
The wife ends up being like a surrogate mother to these weird, murderous kids.
I think the locals stay away from the are where these kids are, they're afraid maybe?
There was a guy there besides the couple and he got killed at some point, I think? Or maybe just ran off and deserted them, either way the BULK of the movie had just the couple and no other on screen people besides the kids.
The kids were all either Asian or Latino (I remember they all had black hair and dark eyes) and were underdressed, either fully nude, or loincloths or makeshift clothes or just shorts or something like that.

I wish I had actual scenes, dialogue, or something more specific to offer, but as I said, it was years ago and my memory isn't the best. 
The visual quality, as I recall, had a low-budget feel to it, so it's possible it was done in mockumentary or found-footage style ...or maybe it was just a low-budget movie, lol. 
I routinely watch a lot underground movies and foreign films and subtitled stuff, so the movie could be from anywhere and/or be an obscure film as well.
This may or may not be relevant, but whenever I think of this movie, Cannibal Holocaust comes to mind as well...?

Reminds me of Who Can Kill a Child? (AKA Island of the Damned) from 1976 and its remake Come Out And Play from 2012, but the kids aren't Asian and the wife meets a different fate.

I think it's the French movie "Vinyan".

Jeanne and Paul are a wealthy couple who were in Thailand helping to
  establish an orphanage when the 2004 tsunami leveled the island.
  Jeanne and Paul had a young son who disappeared in the storm, and
  since his body has never been found, Jeanne holds out hope that he
  might still be alive, a hope that becomes a desperate concern when she
  sees a video of children being held by kidnappers in Burma which shows
  a child who looks like her boy. Eager to find out the truth, Paul pays
  a hefty fee to local outlaw Mr. Gao to escort him and Jeanne into a
  forbidden zone known only to Thailand's criminal underclass near the
  Burmese border. Jeanne and Paul soon find themselves out of their
  depth in a strange land they do not understand where dangerous men
  commune with the spirits of the dead.

And Jeanne indeed ends up taking care of the "children" in the jungle.
